# I have a German resident permit, but want to visit London for two weeks holidays how do I apply for my entry Visa.

Tags: visas

I have a German resident permit, but want to visit London how do I apply for my entry Visa.

Comment: There is a UK government web site that should tell you all about it: https://www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa

Comment: For almost all visa questions your nationality is essential, as that and not your residency makes whether you are able to travel to other countries or need visa. Please edit your question with your nationality and the kind of resident permit you have for Germany (as that might influence the situation.)